# Abbreviation with no indent in .vimrc

Tags: vim

In my .vimrc, I set a shortcut command for define main function.

```
autocmd FileType  c,cpp abbr intmain int main(){<C-M><C-M>  return 0;<C-M><C-M>}
```

When I type `intmain` in my *cpp* file or *c* file, the main function is supposed to be defined as follows.

```
int main(){
  return 0; // two-spaces indent
}
```

However, actual definition goes as follows.

```
int main(){
  return 0; // two-spaces indent
  } // extra two-spaces indent...
```

How can I fix this one?

Comment: I would suggest that you should use some snippet plugin for this kind of thing. I personally use [Ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) but there are others

Answer (score 0):

The error likely occurs because of an interaction with your default settings for c/cpp files.  When I insert your command and type `intmain` the result is

```
int main(){

        return 0; // has 2x4 spaces!

}
```

This is because of my clang config file:

```
$ cat .vim/after/c.vim
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set noexpandtab
```

For optimal results, type as the `autocmd` exactly what you would type into an open buffer with a .c/.cpp extension.